# DataTables not showing data

Tags: javascript, datatables

Hi I have the following data but cannot get DataTables to display it:

```
const data = [{
      "School":"Arsenal 2011",          
      "Group":{
         "Name":"Previous",             
         "ParentGroup":{
            "Name":"Arsenal",           
            "ParentGroup":{
               "Name":"USA",            
               "ParentGroup":null
            }
         }
      },
      "GroupDisplayText":null,
      "Publisher":"Abbot",
      "PublishedDate":"2011",
      "PublishersWebsite":"http://google.com/USA/ADW%202011/Arsenal%202011.pdf"
   },
   {
      "School":"New York 2000",
      "Group":{
         "Name":"New York",
         "ParentGroup":{
            "Name":"USA",
            "ParentGroup":null
         }
      },
      "GroupDisplayText":null,
      "Publisher":"DoE",
      "PublishedDate":"2000",
      "PublishersWebsite":"http://google.com/USA/New York%202000%20Tables.pdf"
   }];


    $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#example').DataTable( {
            "ajax": data
         } );
    }
```

I have created a project on  playcode

https://playcode.io/470603

I am getting a datatables error

DataTables warning: table id=example - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

I have checked the json and all is ok?

Thanks

Comment: The ajax property is for when you are getting the data from a server, but as you are loading the data locally you need to use {data: data} rather than {ajax: data}. However, this produces a different error. For correct data structure and input check the manual: https://datatables.net/manual/data/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#example').DataTable( {
            data:data // ajax for to make ajax request to retrieve data.
            "columns": [ // also needs to specify column config to display it
             { "data": "School" },      
             ] 
         } );
    }
```

for javascript object use data instead.